# grepping using the "|" alternative operator

Tags: regex, linux, grep

The following is a sample of a large file named AT5G60410.gff:

```
Chr5    TAIR10  gene    24294890    24301147    .   +   .   ID=AT5G60410;Note=protein_coding_gene;Name=AT5G60410
Chr5    TAIR10  mRNA    24294890    24301147    .   +   .   ID=AT5G60410.1;Parent=AT5G60410;Name=AT5G60410.1;Index=1
Chr5    TAIR10  protein 24295226    24300671    .   +   .   ID=AT5G60410.1-Protein;Name=AT5G60410.1;Derives_from=AT5G60410.1
Chr5    TAIR10  exon    24294890    24295035    .   +   .   Parent=AT5G60410.1
Chr5    TAIR10  five_prime_UTR  24294890    24295035    .   +   .   Parent=AT5G60410.1
Chr5    TAIR10  exon    24295134    24295249    .   +   .   Parent=AT5G60410.1
Chr5    TAIR10  five_prime_UTR  24295134    24295225    .   +   .   Parent=AT5G60410.1
Chr5    TAIR10  CDS 24295226    24295249    .   +   0   Parent=AT5G60410.1,AT5G60410.1-Protein;
Chr5    TAIR10  exon    24295518    24295598    .   +   .   Parent=AT5G60410.1
```

I am having some trouble extracting specific lines from this using grep.  I wanted to extract all lines that are of type "gene" or type "exon", specified in the third column. I was suprised when this did not work:

```
grep 'gene|exon' AT5G60410.gff
```

No results are returned. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Try `egrep` instead.

Comment: is egrep closer to the kind of regex that Perl uses? (this is the one I have used before)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You need to escape the `|`.  The following should do the job.

```
grep "gene\|exon" AT5G60410.gff
```

Comment: argh, just realised I was following the wrong regex tutorial for use in grep. I can't seem to find a good grep one anywhere. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 58):

By default, grep treats the typical special characters as normal characters unless they are escaped. So you could use the following:

```
grep 'gene\|exon' AT5G60410.gff
```

However, you can change its mode by using the following forms to do what you are expecting:

```
egrep 'gene|exon' AT5G60410.gff
grep -E 'gene|exon' AT5G60410.gff
```

Answer (score 32):

This is a different way of grepping for a few choices:

```
grep -e gene -e exon AT5G60410.gff
```

the `-e` switch specifies different patterns to match.

Comment: now the question is what is faster? does anybody know?

Comment: @stalinko: you should be able to use the `time` command to find out.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
grep "gene\|exon" AT5G60410.gff
```

Comment: Which *value* does this answer have which this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6775943/3933332 doesn't have?

Comment: @Rizier123 -- look at the timestamps, both answered at nearly identical times with the same answer.

Comment: Yup, just one minute late. Still, I'd delete an answer that is identical to the upvoted answer. Especially if had were 40k reputation under my belt.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while googling for a particular problem I was having involving a [piped command](http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/pipes.html) to a `grep` command that used the alternation operator in a regex, so I thought that I would contribute my more specialized answer.

The error I faced turned out to be with the previous pipe operator (i.e. `|`) and not the alternation operator (i.e. `|` identical to pipe operator) in the grep regex at all. The answer for me was to properly escape and quote as necessary [special shell characters such as &](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) before assuming the issue was with my grep regex that involved the alternation operator.

For example, the command I executed on my local machine was:

```
get http://localhost/foobar-& | grep "fizz\|buzz"
```

This command resulted in the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

This error was corrected by changing my command to:

```
get "http://localhost/foobar-&" | grep "fizz\|buzz"
```

By escaping the `&` character with double quotes I was able to resolve my issue. The answer had nothing to do with the alternation operation at all.