# Search for three words written in different "shapes" using grep

Tags: regex, grep, regex-group, cyrillic

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
**gvožđa gvozda gvozdja
гвожђа
```

It’s four words, but each means one thing: iron.

The "d", "dj", "đ", "ђ" are four letters indicating a one "phone".

I am using the following grep formula to search for these three words:

```
grep '\s*[gг][vв]o[žжz](dj|[dđђ])a\s*' filename
```

This grep command gives no output at all. Why?
It should gives all these words in the file:

```
gvožđa
gvozda
gvozdja
гвожђа
```

Comment: You forgot `-E` , `grep -E '\s*[gг][vв]o[žжz](dj|[dđђ])a\s*'`. Or escape `|` (will work in GNU `grep`), and also the `(` and `)` since you are using a POSIX BRE pattern.

Comment: Using the `grep -E` does not solve this issue.

Comment: [grepping using the "|" alternative operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775904/grepping-using-the-alternative-operator) does not solve my problem.

Comment: If I run this `egrep '\s*[gг][vв]o[žжz](dj|[dđђ])a\s*' filename` then I get this output: **gvožđa gvozda gvozdja** but not get this **гвожђа**. It should gives this too: **гвожђа**.

Comment: Correct, you did not explain the issue in the question. This happens because Cyrillic `а` is not equal to ASCII `a` letter. Same goes for `o` and `о`. Use `grep -Eo '[gг][vв][oо][žжz](dj|[dđђ])[aа]'`. Actually, I do not understand why you use `\s*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs due to the fact that your pattern does not match Cyrillic `о` and `а`, and because you use a POSIX ERE pattern without the `-E` option.

You can use

```sh
grep -Eo '[gг][vв][oо][žжz](dj|[dđђ])[aа]' filename
```

Using `\s*` does not actually make sense as it only matches zero or more whitespace chars (only in GNU `grep`).

I added `-o` option here to output all matches, not just matched lines.

See the [online grep demo](https://ideone.com/QOTiBZ).